# separator on non-li markup

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In my markup (bootstrap) I can't use border to make a separator between 2 item

```
<div class="status-wrap">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 straight-line">
        <span>Interview Invitation</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
        <span>Invited 7 Jan 2014</span>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

[**DEMO here**](http://bootply.com/104902)

Comment: Question, are all those classes necessary in the two wrapped div's? looks to me you are doing responsive layout with @media screen probably. I'm just thinking there is a more elegant way to go about doing this. Welcome to SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you wanted to do:
http://bootply.com/104903

There are a couple things here:

1. I added a style so that the there was a border on the straight-line div.
2. I made sure that the divs that were inside of your status-wrap were set to 100% height, this made them take up the whole height of the parent, extending the line all the way from top to bottom.

## css

```
.status-wrap {
  text-align: center;
  background: #EEE;
  height: 40px;
  margin-left: -20px;
  margin-right: -10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.status-wrap div {
  padding-top: 12px;
  height: 100%;
}

.straight-line {
  border-right: 1px solid black; 
}
```

In the markup all I did was remove the bottom div. If you were looking for a clearfix div there are couple more style properties to add, like height:0px;visibility:hidden; etc. This will hide the div while applying the clearfix. The reason you don't need the clearfix at this point is because you aren't floating any of the children in that particular container, so it was just extra markup.

firebug/chrome inspector are great tools for debugging these things because they will tell you clearly and right away what is where and what it is doing.

Comment: It is wired how we both used same code but items showed up differently in two different services :).. Yeah yours works just as well since he is using `.straight-line` class.. I am just wondering why are they lined up on top of each other in my jsFiddler. I +1 your answer.

Comment: so it's just one property to fix my problem? which is the height 100%, how it work?

Comment: The height 100% causes the child div to extend to the height of the parent div, normally the height of a div is set to auto, which allows the content of the div to the decide the div's height. In this case since you want the separator to extend across the height of the parent div, we set the child div's height to 100% (this makes it the same height as the parent div) -- keep in mind if you add padding/etc to this child div it will become 100% + whatever padding there is. If you see problems like that box-sizing:border-box will help : http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are trying to have a border between elements top and bottom so I got you this:

jsFiddler: http://jsfiddle.net/theStudent/sU2yu/

**CSS**

```
.status-wrap {
  text-align: center;
  background: #EEE;
  height: 40px;
  margin-left: -20px;
  margin-right: -10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
}
.status-wrap div {
  padding-top: 12px;
}
```

All I did is added a bottom border to top div.